# A guide about Java TV API

Tags: java, network-monitoring, dvb, transport-stream, dvblast

I want to write a Transport Stream (TS) monitoring program for monitoring media streams on the network. I want to monitor what streams are alive and if possible capture information about them. I want to use a free open source framework not applications such as [this](http://www.tsreader.com/tsreader/index.html). I am a java programmer and found out [Java TV API 1.1 (JSR-927)](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr927/overview-summary.html) is a java framework for my purpose. I found out several resources and java-docs about that But I didn't find any example program using this framework. All I see are some java interfaces and I am confused how to use them in a practical program. Is it needed to use a DVB framework such as [videoLan DVBLast](http://www.videolan.org/projects/dvblast.html) for using it? If someone knows about usage of this framework; It will be so useful to me.